# Decorating Angular-UI Bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-decorator

I have a feature that I am building that is about 90% of the functionality the Angular-UI Bootstrap Modal provides. The only difference is:

- The modal needs to be positioned relative to a container div (I've already handled the styling aspect with the `windowClass`)

At issue is that the `$modalStack service` [hard codes the `body.append` call](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L257), as seen here:

```
body.append(modalDomEl)
body.addClass(OPENED_MODAL_CLASS)
```

[Step one is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3PaR9jTMg9ZiGMb9vu9)

I started by simply copying / pasting the `open` methods on each service (renaming as openWithinElement), and modifying what I needed to make it work. As you can see, if you run the app, it throws an error on the $q dependency not being defined. Okay, I guess that makes sense.

Next I added the dependencies to the `provider.decorator` method, which bypassed all dependency errors. But then I was getting another error, `function getTemplatePromise is undefined` ... well of course it isn't defined. [It's an internal method to the service.](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L348)

That's when I got truly stuck. It seems impossible to decorate this service with a new method, without redefining all of the private functions / objects / props within the service.

Is that the case?

[EDIT TO ADD]
I ultimately ended up decorating the service with an `updateParentElement` method, which then moved the modal to the passed in element, which was executed in the .opened promise. It's hacky, but works, but I'm hoping there's something I'm missing with decorators. 
[/EDIT]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution as I see it will be to provide specific windowClass, then after dialog is open find its element by that class and move it to the container.

Comment: Yeah if you see my edit, more or less that's what I did - just abstracted the functionality out to a decorated $modal service. The crux of my question is - if decorator is truly designed to "monkey patch" a service, why then do I have to reinject everything & re-define internal members. Doesn't make sense.